# Change directory ftpwebrequest

Tags: c#, directory, ftpwebrequest

Trying to upload file to FTP. When logged in I am set in directory /out, need to go back one directory and then up to directory /in before upload. I have this code:

```
       FtpWebRequest req = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("FTP://ftps.something.xx/%2fin/FILENAME.TXT");
       req.EnableSsl = true;
       req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
       req.KeepAlive = false;
       req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
       req.UseBinary = true;
       req.ContentLength = Exportfile.Length;
       req.UsePassive = true;
```

In the logg from the server everyting works fine up until the STOR command is sent wich looks like this:

STOR /in/FILENAME.TXT

This in turn gets a 500 Error "Path change not allowed". I thought the solution with /%2fin/ would send commands for going down one notch and then command for up to /in directory. Or have I missed something? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read about `FtpWebRequest`, you need to use `%e2%e2/in/` instead of `/%2fin/`

`%e2%e2/in/` should be the equivalent of :

cd ..
  cd in

instead of the `/%2fin/` which is equivalent to:

cd /
  cd in

`cd /` means cd root.